# supervisor can't import schedule

Tags: python-3.x, supervisord, schedule, spawn

I try use instead time.sleep schedule functions but I have error

> package containing module schedule is not listed in project
>   requirements

in file with error it's look like

> supervisor: couldn't exec
>   /home/darek/PycharmProjects/Small_programs/shell_scripts/test/test_s.py:
>   ENOEXEC supervisor: child process was not spawned

when I use code:

```
import requests, time, schedule, threading
from my_status import *



def superviorTask():
    r = requests.get('https://medium.com')

    if r.status_code == 200 and len(r.text) > 0:
        status = STATUS_LIVE
    else:
        status = STATUS_INACTIVE  # record to my database that the supervisor is running



def threadTask(job_function):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_function)
    job_thread.start()


# start schedule
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(threadTask, superviorTask)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

and when I try below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
import schedule


schedule.every(10).seconds.do(print("schedule tests!"))

while True:
    print(f"You run test program using Supervisor at {datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')}.")
    print("Good job Darek :)!!!")
    print("...")
    time.sleep(5)
```

I have error:

> import schedule ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/darek/PycharmProjects/Small_programs/shell_scripts/test/test_s.py",
>   line 5, in  import schedule ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'schedule' Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File"/home/darek/PycharmProjects/Small_programs/shell_scripts/test/test_s.py",
>   line 5, in  import schedule ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'schedule'

Answer (score 0):

The default version of schedule package in python 2.7
If you have 3. version forward, you need to specify it:
`pip3 install schedule` (at CMD)